# Gulp: Rename certain file from source directory while copying

Tags: gulp

I would like to copy a folder to another destination and rename a certain file in the same process.

`gulp.task('deploy', function () {
    gulp.src(['xxx/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('yyy'));
});`

I am able to copy the folder over just fine but how would I go about renaming the file?

Source folder structure:

```
- xxx (root)
  - scripts
    - config
      - app.config.local.js (would like to rename this file as app.config.js)
      - app.config.dev.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) plugin to rename files and the [`gulp-if`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) plugin to make sure the renaming is only applied to one particular file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var _if = require('gulp-if');

gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  return gulp.src(['xxx/**/*'])
    .pipe(_if('**/app.config.local.js', rename({basename:'app.config'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('yyy'));
});
```