# gulp: how to change file names/extensions in the same directory

Tags: gulp

I use different `.json` files for configuration of *production* and *staging* mode.

```
// config.production.json
{
  themeColor: "#a35732",
  serverURL: "https://.../production/",
  ...
}

// config.staging.json
{
  themeColor: "#36d1d1",
  serverURL: "https://.../staging/",
  ...
}
```

Before packing (bundling), one of `config.production.json` or `config.staging.json` will be converted to `config.json`, and then be packed into the app bundle. My project code will use `config.json` to run.

I want to use `gulp` to convert one of `*.production.json` or `*.staging.json` into `*.json` before packing. How can I do to achieve this using `gulp`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp: Rename certain file from source directory while copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113143/gulp-rename-certain-file-from-source-directory-while-copying)

Comment: Thanks @SvenSchoenung, it's what I want.